# How to get multiple value from html inputs that generated by C#

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, sql-server-2008-r2

I have multiple Html inputText that is generated on page load by C#. This is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[CharacteristicsFetch]
AS
BEGIN
    SELECT chId, chName, chDesc
    FROM Characteristics
    ORDER BY chName
END
```

and my C# code:

```
public string generate_CharValues()
{
    string post = "";

    DataTable dt = cls.Fill_In_DataTable("CharacteristicsFetch");

    if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            post += "<input id='" + dt.Rows[i]["chId"] + "' name='txt" + dt.Rows[i]["chId"] + "' title='" + dt.Rows[i]["chName"] + "' type='number' required='required' />";
        }   
    }

    return post;
}
```

I called this function from an `.aspx` page that I want use it:

```
charValues = cls.generate_CharValues();
```

The code will generate multiple html inputs that user must provide values for. Each input text has an Id related to it's database Id. Now I want get input values and input Ids then put them on a datatable to send it to database.

This is my try on submit test button:

```
DataTable dtChar = new DataTable();

dtChar.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] {
        new DataColumn("chId", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("animalId", typeof(string)),
        new DataColumn("Rank", typeof(string))});

string animalId = "1";//animalId
int getcount = int.Parse(clsData.Select_One_Data("CharacteristicsGetCount", "chCount").ToString());

for(int i = 0; i < getcount; i++)
{
    string chId = "";//input text id
    string rank = "";//Request.Form["input text value"]
    dtChar.Rows.Add(chId, animalId, rank);
}
```

any method with JS or JQuery will help me too. Thanks

Comment: im using sqlserver 2008 r2 and asp.net 4.0

Answer (score 0):

i am sorry for the wrong answer 
i was in hurry
try this 
it wok for me and returns list of strings

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClientClick="check()"  />
        <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" Text="Button"  OnClick="Button1_Click"/>
       <input type="hidden" id="hdn" runat="server" />
    </div>
    <script>
            function check() {
            var val = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
            var d = "";
            for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
                if (val[i].value != null && val[i].type == 'number') {
                    d += val[i].value+',';
                }
            }
            d = d.slice(0, d.length-1);
            document.getElementById("hdn").value = d;
        }
</script>
</form>
```

and the code behind

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  string  cd = hdn.Value;
 List<string> values =cd.Split(',').ToList();
}
```

Comment: sorry doesn't work, and not related to my question :|

Comment: you can do the onclintclick and the onclick for the same button